# PHP strtotime() "noon" must go before date

Tags: php

The PHP [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function claims to be able to handle "noon" and "midnight" but it's not working for me.

```
$noon_timestamp = strtotime("August 3 noon");
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $noon_timestamp);
1969-12-31 19:00:00
```

However, this does work:

```
$twelve_timestamp = strtotime("August 3 12:00 PM");
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $twelve_timestamp);
2015-08-03 12:00:00
```

I found this did work:

```
$noon_timestamp = strtotime("noon August 3");
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $noon_timestamp).PHP_EOL;
2015-08-03 12:00:00
```

But I'm not sure why I need to move "noon" to before the date. Seems like it should work either way. I know users will try both methods.

**EDIT:** I think I've found a relevant note in the PHP docs under [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php):

> Exceptions to this rule are: "yesterday", "midnight", "today", "noon" and "tomorrow". Note that "tomorrow 11:00" and "11:00 tomorrow" are different. Considering today's date of "July 23rd, 2008" the first one produces "2008-07-24 11:00" where as the second one produces "2008-07-24 00:00". The reason for this is that those five statements directly influence the current time.

I don't understand the last sentence. "Directly influence the current time" ? That seems irrelevant to the order. "tomorrow 11:00" and "11:00 tomorrow" mean the same thing in English.

Comment: Because, while PHP's strtotime() function tries to be clever, it doesn't have human levels of intelligence built in

Comment: If the date parse splits the details of "tomorrow 11:00", it will generate the date for tomorrow, and then adjust to `11:00` on that date; if it works the same way with "11:00 tomorrow", it will generate `11:00` today, and then adjust to the start of `tomorrow`

Comment: @Rizier123 that doc is two clicks away from the function documentation. I'm not going to read the _entire_ manual in hopes this is documented _somewhere_. I found the doc by Googling. We're trying to create a Q&A site here, not bare pointers to the manual.

Comment: @MarkBaker, you should put that in an answer.  Don't worry about Rizier as his would been marked by the answer police as "Not an answer" because its a link only answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a general solution, but I made this function:

```php
function arrange_timestring($timestring) {
    $problematic_keywords = array("noon","midnight");
    $keyword_counter = 0;
    foreach($problematic_keywords as $keyword) {
        if (strpos($timestring,$keyword) !== false) {
            $keyword_counter += 1;
            if (strpos($timestring,$keyword) > 0) {
                $timestring = str_replace($keyword, "", $timestring);
                $timestring = $keyword." ".$timestring;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($keyword_counter > 1) {
        return Null; //strings shouldn't have both noon and midnight
    } else {
    return $timestring;
    }
}
```

Then my code works as expected:

```
$noon_timestamp = strtotime(arrange_timestring("August 3 noon"));
$twelve_timestamp = strtotime(arrange_timestring("August 3 12:00 PM"));
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $noon_timestamp);
2015-08-03 12:00:00
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $twelve_timestamp);
2015-08-03 12:00:00
```